# Does ARC retain objects alloced inside a method parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

My knowledge of ARC has been tested today, i stumbled on [this article](http://blog.harbinger-systems.com/2014/04/ios-memory-management-and-arc/) and it has an example under the heading "Nesting of statements" which in my mind seems wrong.

[image: example]

In the example they show embedded above, the line highlighted with a green underline says that the string alloced inside the function would first get a retain count +1 when being created, then +1 again when adding to the array, then once the array is nil'ed after the for loop, the retain count of the string would be reduced by 1, leaving the original string with a retain count of 1, thus not being dealloced.

I would have assumed the compiler would have been smart enough to at least make an object like that not actually have a retain count initially, since if you just had

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Name 1"]];
```

this string being alloced would have nothing pointing to it and would be released when the autorelease pool comes to an end instead of having a retain count of 1 forever. so why would it have different behaviour when its in a parameter of a function? (unless that line does have a retain count of 1 and this is somehow a memory leak? otherwise it could have a retain count of 1 till the end of its scope at most surely, but then that logic would apply if its a parameter as well i would assume)

Is this article wrong or is my understanding of ARC flawed?

Comment: Article is wrong. And why they keep showing `alloc init`, while we have convenience methods for use in method scopes... Weird.

Comment: The article is wrong (as pointed out below). You'll find the gory details in http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#retained-return-values: *"When receiving a return result from such a function or method, ARC releases the value at the end of the full-expression it is contained within, subject to the usual optimizations for local values."* – Both `name = nil` and `array = nil` are not required to "help ARC release memory".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is wrong.

Your understanding is essentially correct, though the autorelease pool is not used in this case. The sub-expression:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Name 1"]];
```

returns an owned object, as do all `init` methods. That object is passed to `addObject:` and the array also takes ownership. After that ARC sees the string is no longer required by the method and relinquishes its ownership - leaving the array as the only owner.

HTH

Comment: ah i see, so if it wasnt a parameter, it just relinquishes its ownership immediately after being declared, but at that point is it dealloced, or does it get to the end of the autorelease pool before being dealloced? (im assuming the former since you mentioned the autorelease pool not being used, but seems a bit ambiguous which case you are talking about, just want to clarify)

Comment: The auto release pool isn't used in this case because it's not an auto released object.

Answer (score 4):

ARC is not flawed here. Sounds like the article is wrong.

ARC will release the allocated parameter object as expected while the array keeps its reference. Once the array is released, the object will have no more references and it will also be deallocated, as expected.

Comment: if we can get a few more people to agree with us, then maybe ill post this in the articles comment section to maybe alert them or anyone else that finds the article